# Javamail recieved mail send back to sender as bounce mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, gmail-imap

I am quite confuse handling a mail. Once i received mail in my inbox e.g. (gmail), can i able to send back to user as it is bounce mail.
What i am doing in here is, my application read mail from gmail using Javamail API and i want to send back them as that their email has not been delivered.

Any one have face this kind of scenario?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bouncing a message is MTA's job, not a client's such as JavaMail. You can however **fake** a bounce message but anyone looking into the message's source will be able to tell it was sent from a client.

Comment: I solved the issue, now i can make bounce back mail from java code.